# Why does this operation break when turned into a function (AutoHotKey/AHK)

Tags: function, com, macros, ms-office, autohotkey

The following operation works correcting inside AHK. It replaces the word ted with the word tom inside an open word document.

**Working Code**

```
; Word Constants
    vbTrue := -1
    wdReplaceNone := 0
    wdFindContinue := 1
    return

#IfWinActive, ahk_exe WINWORD.EXE
^7::
    try
       oWord := ComObjActive("Word.Application")
    catch
       return

    FindText := "ted"
    ReplaceWith := "tom"

    oFind := oWord.Selection.Find
    oHyperlinks := oWord.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks

    oFind.ClearFormatting
    oFind.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    while oFind.Execute(FindText, vbTrue, false,,,,, wdFindContinue,,, wdReplaceNone)
        oHyperlinks.Add(oWord.Selection.Range, "http://www.autohotkey.com",,, ReplaceWith)
    return
```

However, when I turn this exact same code into a function it does not work. It does not work when written this way, and it also does not work even if the parameters are removed and the variables are put back into the script.

**Broken Code (with parameters)**

```
ReplaceAndLink(FindText, ReplaceWith)
    {
    ; Word Constants
        vbTrue := -1
        wdReplaceNone := 0
        wdFindContinue := 1
        return
    try
       oWord := ComObjActive("Word.Application")
    catch
       return

    oFind := oWord.Selection.Find
    oHyperlinks := oWord.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks

    oFind.ClearFormatting
    oFind.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    while oFind.Execute(FindText, vbTrue, false,,,,, wdFindContinue,,, wdReplaceNone)
        oHyperlinks.Add(oWord.Selection.Range, "http://www.autohotkey.com",,, ReplaceWith)
    return
    }


#IfWinActive, ahk_exe WINWORD.EXE
^7::

ReplaceAndLink("ted", "tom")
```

**Broken Code (without parameters)**

```
ReplaceAndLink(FindText, ReplaceWith)
    {
    ; Word Constants
        vbTrue := -1
        wdReplaceNone := 0
        wdFindContinue := 1
        return
    try
       oWord := ComObjActive("Word.Application")
    catch
       return

    FindText := "ted"
    ReplaceWith := "tom"

    oFind := oWord.Selection.Find
    oHyperlinks := oWord.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks

    oFind.ClearFormatting
    oFind.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    while oFind.Execute(FindText, vbTrue, false,,,,, wdFindContinue,,, wdReplaceNone)
        oHyperlinks.Add(oWord.Selection.Range, "http://www.autohotkey.com",,, ReplaceWith)
    return
    }


#IfWinActive, ahk_exe WINWORD.EXE
^7::

ReplaceAndLink()
```

Troubleshooting Notes:

- Word is open during both operations
- I am using the newest version of AHK
- I have tried running the broken one on a clean restart
- No special libraries or other AHK scripts are running

Also... I know that similar COM based AHK scripts can be placed into functions... see for example:

```
LinkCreator(FindText, ReplaceWith)
    {
        oWord := ComObjActive("Word.Application")
        oWord.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        oWord.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

        oWord.Selection.Find.Execute(FindText, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, ReplaceWith, 2)
    }

F2::
       LinkCreator("store", "town")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling [`return`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Return.htm) before the function can finish. This causes the script to stop processing that function and return to the caller.

```
ReplaceAndLink(FindText, ReplaceWith)
{
; Word Constants
    vbTrue := -1
    wdReplaceNone := 0
    wdFindContinue := 1
    return <---------- HERE
try
   oWord := ComObjActive("Word.Application")
catch
   return
```

Try removing that and it should execute as expected.

A simple troubleshooting tip for when something isn't executing is to place a [`Soundbeep`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SoundBeep.htm) or [`MsgBox`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/MsgBox.htm) somewhere in the code to see if you have some unreachable code and work backwards from there.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! I really appreciate the help. I removed the return's and it is still not working. Here is the updated code: http://i.imgur.com/TFUQKjm.png

Comment: Wait.  It works. You were EXACTLY right. I over compensated and deleted all the returns. I needs the other ones just not the one you pointed to. Thank you!